# Can convert RCA to USB?

Tags: recorder, cable

I have [Boss BR 600 recorder](https://www.boss.info/us/products/br-600/) and this device have 2 RCA line out.

[image]

Is a way to connect this line out to USB for sound quality?

Thanks

Comment: It already has USB... right next to those 2 sockets. Read the manual for how to use it.

Comment: @Tetsujin This recorder has USB but if you want to use this, you must first record voice in internal recorder SD card and then going to setting and select export data. Then USB will be active. But I need live sound on USB port.

Answer (score 1):

You need a USB soundcard with line inputs (balanced or unbalanced) to connect this device in analog to USB, and suitable cables/adapters.  Such soundcards can be pretty tiny and cheap these days.  There is no real ceiling on the size and price you can pay if you want to get better quality.

However, for non-live purposes you'd be better served by reading out the data via the BR-600's own USB interface: that way no AD/DA conversion intervenes.  For analog purposes, just plug the analog line outs *directly* into an amp.  It doesn't get better than that.

So it's not quite clear what you hope to achieve by tapping the device's analog output and getting that information live in digital.

Comment: Thanks, but soundcard convert stereo jack 3.5 mm to USB and my laptop have input mic port. I can connect recorder to laptop by AUX cable but input laptop mic port have a noise. I think if get live voice from recorder to laptop by USB, I have't noise. Is right?